# Unable to populate Dropdown menu using extendedChoice parameter in Jenkins build Dynamically (using groovy script)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, extended-choice-parameter

[Jenkins build with parameters option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzuQP.png)

Unable to find out why my groovy script is not running?

```
        parameters {
            extendedChoice(
                bindings: 'image=image', 
                defaultValue: '', 
                description: 'Build', 
                groovyClasspath: '', 
                groovyScript: '''
                        import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
                        import java.util.logging.Logger
                        logger.info("****####")
                        def result = 
                        "https://localhost:8080/$image/tag".toURL().text; 
                        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper(); 
                        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(result);
                        value = object[0].Value
                        println value
                        def decoded = value.decodeBase64()
                        return String(decoded), 
                multiSelectDelimiter: ',', 
                name: 'BUILD', 
                quoteValue: false, 
                saveJSONParameterToFile: false, 
                type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                visibleItemCount: 5)
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the Pipeline code you are trying so we can better assist you.

Comment: Thanks @ycr. It is all about my groovy script inside extendedChoice parameter. Unable to figure where I can see the output and why is it not populating dropdown

Comment: have you checked your jenkins log? there should be an exception and stacktrace in there that can help you figuring out what is wrong. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/

Comment: Used the below code to get the log stack. But it is directly giving me the output of pipeline whether it's SUCCESS or FAILED
import java.util.logging.Logger
logger.info("****####")